# Call method with splats arguments in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

How to call method with splats, like `fn *args, 2`? Example:

```
def calculate(&block : (Int32, Int32) -> String)
  block.call(1, 2)
end

def operation(a : Int32, b : Int32, type : String)
  [a, type, b].join(" ")
end

p calculate{|a, b| operation a, b, "+"}
```

This won't work

```
p calculate{|*args| operation *args, "+"}
```

Comment: Calling a method with splat arguments is not the issue here. Splat arguments don't work with procs (captured blocks). A proc must have fixed arguments, so this wouldn't be much useful anyway. What exactly is your question, what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `calculate` expects a block that takes two integers as input but `calculate` is invoked with a block that accepts a tuple as input.  Changing `calculate` as follows allows the use of splats.

```
def calculate(&block : (Tuple(Int32, Int32)) -> String)
  block.call({1,2})
end
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to call `calculate{|a, b| operation a, b, "+"}` somehow otherwise, without changing its signature to tuple?